# Teradata SQL Timezone adjustments

Tags: sql, timezone, teradata

I have a database where I can see actions taken by users. These actions have a timestamp. All the timestamps are in EST.
Let's say the action is, downloading content.
I need to find, x amount of users downloaded content y in GMT(these users are in GMT).
I need to find, x amount of users downloaded content y in PST(these users are in PST).

I have the mapping of countries etc. However, I can't find a good query which creates a table with the timezone mappings for the database.

Can anyone give me an idea on how I would do the conversion in SQL and point me in the direction of a query which recreates the timezone mapping table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979929/oracle-sql-query-needs-to-change-based-on-timezone Might help..

Comment: Dealing with timezones is quite complicated, there's no simple "timezone mapping table". The "official" data is maintained at http://www.iana.org/time-zones, CVS data is available at http://timezonedb.com/.

If all data is converted to EST during load there's no easy way to get back the original timestamp including the timezone unless you store it in an additional column or as part of the user definition.

Comment: To convert to a different timezone there's "ts_col at -8" or "ts_col at timezone_col". You need to add more details, how the data actually looks like and what exactly you want to get as result.